# Epson Printer SX100 - determine inklevel in Windows 8

Tags: windows, windows-8

How do I find out which inks have run out on my printer Epson SX100.  The light flashes but I cannot get any information in windows 8.

Answer (score 1):

Over the years I've learned; "When all else fails, read the manual".

According to the [manual](ftp://download.epson-europe.com/pub/download/3214/epson321440eu.pdf) on Epson's site, the cartridges have an indicator on them so you can tell which one is expended.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

According to [Microsoft](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Check-ink-levels-on-a-printer):

"If your printer produces blurry, faint, or incomplete copies, it might be low on ink. There is **no universal method** in Windows to check ink levels because it varies by printer. To find out how to check your printer's ink level, refer to the information that came with the printer.

If you suspect a printer is low on ink, it's a good idea to print a test page before you try to print something else. If you can't print black or other colors (or if you can't print at all), the printer might be out of ink, you might need to clean it, or it might have a hardware or driver problem.

For more help, check the information that came with the printer or go to the [printer manufacturer's website](http://www.epson.co.uk/gb/en/viewcon/corporatesite/products/mainunits/support/2777)."

Answer (score 0):

A non computer based approach would involve putting every ink cartridge on a scale and replace them starting with the ones that weigh the least.
That of course assumes that the actual ink level determines if a cartridge is considered empty or not, which is not always the case with Epson (page counters on chips built into the cartridge).